# Extracting the prop types of a component in Vue 3 (typescript) to use them somewhere else

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

Vue can already infer the types of props when you annotate the props under the "props:" key of the component and that is good.

But is there an "utility type" in the vue types which can extract the type of the props from a given component?

Say I have a component defined with defineComponent and the component declaration has a props key which properly defines the names and types of the props. I want an utility type that works like this:

`let someting: PropType<MyComponent> = {...};`

Vue typescript types contain lots of utility types like this but I couldn't find something that does this.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Figured it out; something like the following works:

```
import MyComponent from "./mycomponent.vue";

type MyComponentProps = InstanceType<typeof MyComponent>["$props"];

const props: MyComponentProps = { ... }
```

Comment: I get `MyComponentProps = Record<string, any> | undefined`. Which is pointless.

Comment: For anyone coming into this wondering why it won't work in IntelliJ (with a `<script setup>` component), there is currently an open issue to support this: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-54985/provide-tsserver-extension-to-make-the-language-service-know-vue-files

If you're using VSCode, it will work if you configure your IDE correctly: https://vuejs.org/guide/typescript/overview.html#project-setup

Comment: Using this approach with the new Vue 3.3 component generics, things break: `InstanceType<typeof MyComponent<SomeGeneric>>` _Type 'typeof MyComponent<SomeGeneric>' provides no match for the signature 'new (...args: any): any'_

Comment: But I can't use it to type `defineProps`. The compiler screams `[@vue/compiler-sfc] Unresolvable type reference or unsupported built-in utility type`.

Answer (score 12):

What worked for me is this:

```
import {AllowedComponentProps, Component, VNodeProps} from 'vue';

type ComponentProps<C extends Component> = C extends new (...args: any) => any
  ? Omit<InstanceType<C>['$props'], keyof VNodeProps | keyof AllowedComponentProps>
  : never;
```

**Full working example**

```
import {AllowedComponentProps, Component, PropType, VNodeProps} from 'vue';

type ComponentProps<C extends Component> = C extends new (...args: any) => any
  ? Omit<InstanceType<C>['$props'], keyof VNodeProps | keyof AllowedComponentProps>
  : never;

type Config<C extends Component> = {
  component: C;
  props: ComponentProps<C>;
};

declare function defineConfig<C extends Component>(config: Config<C>): void;

const TestComponent = defineComponent({
  name: 'TestComponent',
  props: {
    disabled: {
      type: Boolean,
    },
    options: {
      type: Array as PropType<{key: string; value: string}[]>,
      required: true,
    },
  },
});

defineConfig({
  component: TestComponent,
  props: { // TS will throw an error because options is required but missing
    // IDE will suggest:
    //   disabled: boolean | undefined
    //   options: {key: string; value: string}[]
  },
});
```

**Why does it need `Omit`?**

Just `InstanceType<C>['$props']` includes properties of `VNodeProps` and `AllowedComponentProps`. So, omitting their properties leaves only the actual props of the component.

**Why does it need `extends`?**

Without checking if `C` extends `new (...args: any) => any`, `InstanceType` will trigger TS error TS2344:

```
TS2344: Type 'C' does not satisfy the constraint 'abstract new (...args: any) => any'.
```

Answer (score 2):

I've stumbled upon an arguably more elegant solution to get the types of the declared props of a component.
*(`$props` is generally fine, but it also includes some other default properties, as well as `on*` aliases for emitted events, so it's not ideal for strict type-checking of `v-bind` objects.)*

The idea is to use the return types of `defineComponent` to access props at various stages. Also some logic for emit event handlers is included:

```
/* FILE: util.ts */
import { ComponentOptionsBase, DefineComponent, EmitsOptions, ObjectEmitsOptions} from "vue";

type DefineComponentReturnType =
  | DefineComponent<any, any>
  | DefineComponent<any, any, any, any, any, any, any, any, any>;

type ExtractOptions<Props = any, Emits extends EmitsOptions = any, Defaults = any> = ComponentOptionsBase<
  Props, any, any, any, any, any, any, Emits, any, Defaults
>;

type PropOptionsToPropTypes<Props, Defaults> = Partial<Defaults> & Omit<Props, keyof Defaults>;

// based on `EmitsToProps` type
type EmitsToEventHandlers<T extends EmitsOptions> = T extends string[]
  ? { [K in T[number]]?: (...args: any[]) => any }
  : T extends ObjectEmitsOptions
  ? {
      [K in keyof T]?: T[K] extends null
        ? (...args: any[]) => any
        : (...args: T[K] extends (...args: infer P) => any ? P : never) => any;
    }
  : Record<string, never>;

// these are the 2 utility types to be used
export type Props<T extends DefineComponentReturnType> = T extends ExtractOptions<infer P, any, infer D>
  ? PropOptionsToPropTypes<P, D>
  : never;

export type EventHandlers<T extends DefineComponentReturnType> = T extends ExtractOptions<any, infer E, any>
  ? EmitsToEventHandlers<E>
  : never;

/* FILE: main.ts */
import { defineComponent } from "vue";
const Component = defineComponent({...});

// example use
type ComponentProps = Props<typeof Component>;
type ComponentEvents = EventHandlers<typeof Component>;
```

An extra perk of these utility types is that default/required prop options are correctly interpreted into TS types (which presented quirks if you tried to declare component props as interfaces, etc).

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.8.4#code/LAKA9AVABAYgkgGQKIC4oFcAuBLANgOkwGcoIxRsBbABwHsAnTKAbygGFabaA7AU28wB5ajh5EAQgEMivADRQAIrwBm2Phy58B8pJWzFho7kXmCARgCteAY0y79RQ9jEBfKMvqcoAIgBu6Xm8AblBQTABPal5FFTVeDTotTAAlXkx0em4AFUjogF5QKCgAHxjVdU5E-kwAHklucPl68IA%20QpKyuISearqGpv6oZoHGocHhsdGJ5paQkDDcqCQAD0x6SVsnMRqABU9qEjzJnT1iKF5V-gATEnsDEWdjKCOJpWVJdFwzl4aW5-ZKj0BFtjFIZDV2ntaAcRrDjvDpoM7iZ4W8Pl8iKBZqEQBEolAodQQUQsrRCTkokRdvsUWjPsQ-kcdpJGNhJLganSMX8AGRQQSnanQlEAa144VoyjK6IZc1AYDAUDM0l4VygPCgAANkaTCURNVA8bwFvidbQkL5qgAJepXXC8ehUrLnS7cG5LU6OB5iRlQZ0XTDXEhENZqADmAG0ALrtAD8LCgEYA0lA1H6I9x0JQzA6o1HY2gABT4EsssNENDNaMASmef2aUBc7TQ-td7vMVlsyOJcZY7SKRWTqe4UDFEqlWXzLeTUZdgbdJEzuFw-YHRXjxdL9HLlYaNbrk1Xa6LJfwZYr6aTs4DQagm7P24vamUDoJtby9YaUHjOygaD4lr0O%20n7hHMa5NiARRoKk1gMFcNQhvQ4byABDrYvM4CKpgAAWvAyEM9DRDh0QAEwYDguD6OEhq5CQmC0Eq0ToDIVygBcdCMDR%20J6jUrbzu6bxdICSSpOkmQUrwvp8beKxrBsQjesYNTPq%20Oxwip9CKG0kHfgS%20zErq%20wSVSalac2UCofQcogOxDBMEaSyWgINpuvajq8XOt6CRUmjVKJGTZLkUmeQuSyrOsmyKVSEwaUsIzaeuHoOKSFrWrablUkg2k4lBFm8IB1mQLAiCoFAlCSGohAkGQFBcJxrBXLEPlVNoenQhJ8j0akygkG4HheH4ATBKAsHGEw3RJP8jXlPEwnVIWzCrtwkiULwaDeBN1TeLIq7UDSaCLTpa5FIGIaEgdR7HSduRoOItC0Pa9RDCQ5K5DUZj3Y93AtDtR1XQOhEAI7oNghFXGgawBJdRQuL9-1jLQxH0FkeGYOdfZ-fDRpoAAyqG3Bhs9bXUBJCH42GP3Q8d00yutp04AT3hUxB4FwwOvCemgEbeBz%20gALT5VtUZs0UMjpNQhZ7cKtaHfDo0hgm9OEgMiO4cjqOEo2-xdSoRCSzS1Zgf9hFiSOrBK-sjarhBLjVjiCouit1D2hgMgmtEm0CHq-w8UakoAr5AjoQ5nt2E53yOWlrkOlSftSqH6FAA)

Answer (score 2):

I use the following type in Vue 3.3+ projects with SFCs and the Composition API:

Component:

```
// MyComponent.vue
<script setup lang="ts">
defineProps<{
  myProp?: string
}>()
</script>
```

Type:

```
type MyComponentProps = Omit<InstanceType<typeof MyComponent>, `$${string}`>
```

The `InstanceType`-part returns the component props and other internal props prefixed with "$":

```
{
    $: ComponentInternalInstance;
    $data: {};
    $props: {
        readonly myProp?: string | undefined;
        key?: string | number | symbol | undefined;
        ... 10 more ...;
        style?: unknown;
    };
    readonly myProp?: string | undefined;
    ... 10 more ...;
};
```

The `Omit`-part filters all props starting with "$":

```
{
    readonly myProp?: string | undefined;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

I try to write a demo to test this thing. And i created three files.

1. 'myselect.d.ts'  to define the type of component props.

```js
import { ExtractPropTypes } from 'vue'
import { ElSelect } from 'element-plus'
export type ElSelectProps = Partial<Omit<InstanceType<typeof ElSelect>, `$${string}`>>
```

2. 'MySelect.vue'   is the component that I want to customize.

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <el-select v-bind="$attrs"></el-select>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { ElSelectProps } from './myselect'
defineProps<ElSelectProps>()
</script>

<style scoped></style>
```

3. 'list.vue'  is the component that tries to use 'MySelect'.

```js
<template>
  <div class="box"> 岗位列表 </div>
  <MySelect v-model="value" :disabled="false" @blur="handleBlur"></MySelect>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref } from 'vue'
import MySelect from './MySelect.vue'
const value = ref(0)
const handleBlur = () => {}
</script>

<style scoped></style>
```

Answer (score 2):

For Vue 3.4.15, I was able to find an answer that meets all of my criteria:

1. Does not require any new exports from the component you are consuming.
2. Does not require modifying how you call `defineComponent()` in the component you are consuming.
3. Understands types and the distinction between required and optional.
4. Brings in only explicitly defined types, not e.g. the fields returned from `data()` or meta-fields like `$`.
5. Can be invoked with a single type parameterization, similar to `ExtractPropTypes<typeof MyComponent>`.

Here is my implementation:

```
// Given a component definition created with defineComponent() and exported from a single-file component, this type is
// the shape of a props object that can be passed to the component.
type ExtractSetupProps<T> = T extends { setup?(props: infer P, ...rest: any[]): any } ?
  P extends any ? P : never
  : never;

type ExtractConstructedProps<T> = T extends { new (...args: any[]): { $props: infer X } } ?
  X extends Record<string, any> ? X : never
  : never;

export type PublicPropsOf<T> = Pick<ExtractConstructedProps<T>, keyof ExtractSetupProps<T>>;
```

How it works:

1. Helper `ExtractSetupProps<>` gets the type of props that will be passed to the setup option. This has the right fields, but it will have filled in all fields with defaults, so if you try to use this to constrain what you pass to the component it will be too restrictive.
2. Helper `ExtractConstructedProps<>` gets the component instance value of `$props`. This has the right types, but it also includes **everything** that can be passed in as a prop, including VNode hooks which I consider extraneous.

By narrowing the type of `ExtractConstructedProps<>` to only the fields that actually get passed in to the setup function:

```
Pick<ExtractConstructedProps<T>, keyof ExtractSetupProps<T>>
```

The final type is a clean representation of what the component needs in order to render.

Answer (score 1):

I'm kinda late to the party but now there is an [awesome `ExtractPropTypes` operator from the *vue* library](https://vuejs.org/api/utility-types.html#extractproptypes) itself.

Comment: This is good to know, but it takes in a _props object_, not a component definition.

Comment: You are right indeed, but somehow `buttonVariant?: ExtractPropTypes<VBtn>['variant']` works for us as expected. Types are (seem to be?) derived and enforced.

Comment: Weird, in my codebase the following `type ButtonProps = ExtractPropTypes<typeof AppButton>;` just gives `type ButtonProps = {[x: string]: any;} & {[x: number]: any;}`. I'm on Vue 3.3 and using script setup. Perhaps you should edit your answer to include an example of how your component is setup and how you're using this built-in operator.

Answer (score 0):

I found a working solution

```js
<script lang="ts">
import { VDialog } from 'vuetify/components';

export default defineComponent<VDialog['$props'], VDialog['$emit']>({});
</script>

<script lang="ts" setup>
const test = ref<string>('hello');
</script>

<template>
  <VDialog maxWidth="500">
    <VCard>
      <VCardTitle>
        <div class="flex justify-between items-center">
          <slot name="title" />
          <span v-if="!$slots.title"> Titre </span>
          <VBtn icon="mdi-close" variant="text" size="small" />
        </div>
      </VCardTitle>
      <hr />
      <VCardText>
        <slot />
        {{ test }}
      </VCardText>
      <hr />
      <VCardActions>
        <slot name="actions" />
      </VCardActions>
    </VCard>
  </VDialog>
</template>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I achieved this using `PropType` and `ExtractPropTypes`. My goal was to share some props between a `Button` component and an `UploadButton` component. I wanted to be able to use the `UploadButton` component like this:

```js
<script lang="ts">
import UploadButton from "./UploadButton.vue"
import { defineComponent } from "vue"

export default defineComponent({
  components: {
    UploadButton,
  },
})
</script>

<template>
  <UploadButton :buttonProps="{ variant: 'primary', iconStart: 'plus' }">
    Add a file
  </UploadButton>
</template>
```

I already had the `Button` component that declared its props like this:

```js
<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent, type PropType } from "vue"

type Variant = "primary" | "secondary"

export default defineComponent({
  props: {
    variant: {
      type: String as PropType<Variant>,
      required: true,
    },


    iconStart: {
      type: String,
      required: false,
    },
  },
})
</script>

<template>
  <!-- not the complete rendering code here since it's not relevant -->
  <button><slot></slot></button>
</template>
```

The first thing I did is to extract the props definition to its own variable and export it:

```js
<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent, type PropType } from "vue"

type Variant = "primary" | "secondary"

export const props = {
  variant: {
    type: String as PropType<Variant>,
    required: true,
  },

  iconStart: {
    type: String,
    required: false,
  },
} as const

export default defineComponent({
  props: {
    variant: {
      type: String as PropType<Variant>,
      required: true,
    }
  },
})
</script>

<template>
  <!-- not the complete rendering code here since it's not relevant -->
  <button><slot></slot></button>
</template>
```

Then on the `UploadButton` component, I imported the `props` from the `Button` component and pass it to the `PropType` and `ExtractPropTypes` utility types:

```js
<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent, type PropType, type ExtractPropTypes } from "vue"
import Button, { props as ButtonProps } from "./Button.vue"

export default defineComponent({
  props: {
    buttonProps: Object as PropType<Partial<ExtractPropTypes<typeof ButtonProps>>>,
    required: false,
    default: {},
  },
  components: {
    Button,
  },
})
</script>

<template>
  <Button :variant="buttonProps.variant ?? 'primary'" :icon-start="buttonProps.iconStart">
    <slot></slot>
  </Button>
</template>
```

Then the API I imagined at the beginning to use the `UploadButton` works great.

Just note that the `as const` for the `props` object is important. Also, I used `ExtractPropTypes`, but you may prefer `ExtractPublicPropTypes`. I didn't really understand the difference between these two.

Answer (score -1):

It's not really want I wanted, but you get some support while using `Partial<InstanceType<typeof MyComponent>>`.

Edit:
Previous answers were accessing the type of ['$props'], but this did not work for me, because there was no type check on the actual props. With partial, I could at least archive some kind of typechecking for a part of the Component, so in my case I could add the prop object and got type checking for it. Problem with this is, that I have to know which of the properties are required, and which not. I hope there is a better answer to this question, but for know I am fine with my solution.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).