# How to import typescript types for vuetify properties like "variant"?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I am building a vue component based on v-btn from vuetify 3. I want to have a variant property which is passed down to the v-btn component I use. I would like to specify the type correctly. Currently my type definition is

```
 variant?: NonNullable<"flat" | "text" | "elevated" | "tonal" | "outlined" | "plain"> | undefined,
```

Is there some way I can import this as a named type from v-btn? I don't like the idea of copying the list of variants into my codebase. I would like something like

```
variant?: Variant | undefined
```

much more.

This is the component I am trying to build:

```
<template>
    <v-tooltip location="bottom">
        <template v-slot:activator="{ props }">
            <v-btn v-bind="props" icon class="icon-right" @click="$emit('onClick')" :variant="$props.variant" :density="$props.density">
            <v-icon> {{ $props.icon }} </v-icon>
            </v-btn>
        </template>
        <span> {{ $props.title }} </span>
    </v-tooltip>
</template>
  
<style scoped lang="scss">
.icon-right {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}
</style>

<script lang="ts" setup>
const props = defineProps<{
  title: string,
  icon: string,
  variant?: NonNullable<"flat" | "text" | "elevated" | "tonal" | "outlined" | "plain"> | undefined,
  density?: null | 'default' | 'comfortable' | 'compact',
}>();
const emit = defineEmits<{
  onClick: []
}>();
</script>
```

Comment: It's not shown how it's supposed to be used. This matters if you intend it for defineProps

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68602712/extracting-the-prop-types-of-a-component-in-vue-3-typescript-to-use-them-somew

Comment: Could you provide a online demo, like codesanbox or stackblitz

Comment: @YuMiao I added the full component for clarification

Comment: @allinonemovie you can try to import type { VBtn } from "vuetify/components", then get the type of variant and density

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can import the type with `import type { VBtn } from "vuetify/components"`

```
import type { VBtn } from "vuetify/components";

type TVariant = VBtn["$props"]['variant'];
type TDensity = VBtn["$props"]['density'];
const props = defineProps<{
  title: string;
  icon: string;
  variant?: TVariant;
  density?: TDensity;
}>();
```

Comment: This solution worked for me for importing src property of VImg.